# JQgrid Angular 13

Tags: angular

Quiero presentar un grid usando el componente de jqgrid en angular , pero me presenta el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya eh usado el jqgrid pero con js puro y no me presenta novedad , sin embargo soy un poco nuevo en angular , eh buscado en internet pero no encuentro la forma se solucionarlo.

**app.component.**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
 
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
 
export class AppComponent {
    source: any =
    {
        localdata: 
        [
            ['Alfreds Futterkiste', 'Maria Anders', 'Sales Representative', 'Obere Str. 57', 'Berlin', 'Germany'],
            ['Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados', 'Ana Trujillo', 'Owner', 'Avda. de la Constitucin 2222', 'Mxico D.F.', 'Mexico'],
            ['Eastern Connection', 'Ann Devon', 'Sales Agent', '35 King George', 'London', 'UK'],
            ['Ernst Handel', 'Roland Mendel', 'Sales Manager', 'Kirchgasse 6', 'Graz', 'Austria']
        ],
        datafields: 
        [
            { name: 'CompanyName', type: 'string', map: '0' },
            { name: 'ContactName', type: 'string', map: '1' },
            { name: 'Title', type: 'string', map: '2' },
            { name: 'Address', type: 'string', map: '3' },
            { name: 'City', type: 'string', map: '4' },
            { name: 'Country', type: 'string', map: '5' }
        ],
        datatype: 'array'
    };
 
dataAdapter: any = new jqx.dataAdapter(this.source);

columns: any[] =
[
    { text: 'Company Name', datafield: 'CompanyName', width: 200 },
    { text: 'Contact Name', datafield: 'ContactName', width: 150 },
    { text: 'Contact Title', datafield: 'Title', width: 100 },
    { text: 'Address', datafield: 'Address', width: 100 },
    { text: 'City', datafield: 'City', width: 100 },
    { text: 'Country', datafield: 'Country' }
];
```

}

**app.module**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 
import { AppComponent }     from './app.component';
import { jqxGridComponent } from 'jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets-ts/angular_jqxgrid';
 
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent, jqxGridComponent ],
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
 
export class AppModule { }
```

Uso el codigo que esta en la pagina oficial:
https://www.jqwidgets.com/angular-components-documentation/documentation/angular-cli/angular-cli-jqxgrid.htm?search=

Comment: veo seguiste exactamente el tutorial de esa pagina intente hacer lo mismo en un proyecto con Angular 12 y me da otro tipo de errores quizás te pueda servir este link https://github.com/jqwidgets/jQWidgets/tree/master/demos/Angular

Comment: Buenas tardes , gracias por tu respuesta ya logré resolverlo. Según lo que me explicaron es por tema de ruta , tenia que agregar un patch en el tsconfig para que se pueda usar en app-node de la librería.